# Calculating Highest Power of 2 That Evenly Divides a Number in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I need to write some logic to determine, given an even number. The highest power of two that evenly divides it.  What is the maximum value of 2^n where Input % 2^n  == 0?

IE:
Input ->  Output

```
4  (0100)  -> 4

8  (1000)  -> 8

12 (1100)  -> 4

14 (1110)  -> 2

24 (11000) -> 8

etc....
```

It looks like there be some bitwise logic that may work out: when looking at the input in binary, the rightmost one bit appears to be solution.  How do I determine this value in C?  Is there another solution that may be easier?

Thanks-
Jonathan

Answer (score 19):

If you are willing to assume 2's complement arithmetic:

`x & -x`

If you do a lot of this sort of thing (or even if you just find it interesting), find yourself a copy of the book "Hacker's Delight".

**edit:** avakar correctly notes that this doesn't depend on 2's complement if the type is unsigned.  The relevant section of the standard is §6.2.5, paragraph 9:

> A computation involving unsigned
>   operands can never overflow, because a
>   result that cannot be represented by
>   the resulting unsigned integer type is
>   reduced modulo the number that is one
>   greater than the largest value that
>   can be represented by the resulting
>   type.

"one greater than the largest value" leaves some wiggle room for an especially perverse implementation (in particular, an implementation that doesn't use binary, for example), but you're pretty unlikely to encounter that.

Comment: +1. For the record, you don't have to assume 2's complement. This will work portably on any architecture, as long as `x` is of unsigned arithmetic type.

Comment: Say we have a 32-bit type with 1's complement arithmetic: if x is 1, then `-x` is `0xfffffffe`, and `x & -x` is 0, which is not the answer the questioner wants.  As J.F. Sebastian notes, you *can* work around this by using `x & (~x+1)`, which is just 2's compliment negation expanded into two operations.

Comment: `(~x + 1)` is two's-complement negation, that is.

Comment: No. For `x` unsigned, `-x` will be `2^k-x` for some `k`. In your example, `k` will be 32 and `-x` will be `0xffffffff`. Again, `unsigned` is the key here, all bets are off for signed `x`.

Answer (score 7):

Without using floating point arithmetic:

```
((x ^ (x - 1)) >> 1) + 1
```

Simplification and edge cases are left as exercises for the reader.

Comment: X = 24

(24 ^ 23) = 24623
24623 >> 1 = 12311
12311 + 1 = 12312

Did I compute something wrong?

Comment: Jonathan: `^` is XOR, so `(24 ^ 23)` is 15.

Comment: BTW, if x is unsigned then I believe the only edge case which needs special handling is zero.

Answer (score 7):

We can replace `(-x)` by `(~x + 1)`:

```
x & (~x+1)
```

[Low Level Bit Hacks You Absolutely Must Know](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/low-level-bit-hacks-you-absolutely-must-know/) provides detailed explanation.

Comment: Note that (~x+1) is the definition of -x in 2's complement.  That makes this a slightly better answer than x & (-x), since (~x+1) only depends on the machine using straight binary arithmetic, which is pretty much a given these days (but wasn't always!).

Answer (score 3):

A number in the form 2^n is written in binary by a 1 followed by a series of 0 or more 0s.
For example, 1, 10, 100, 1000, ... etc. are all power of 2.

To get the highest power of 2 that divides a given number, you can do the following two steps:

1. Write the number in binary form. For example, if the number is 168, write 10101000.
2. Strike off all the bits before the first bit from right hand side that contains 1. In the case of 168, what remains is 1000 (= 8 in decimal) after striking off first part of 10101000.

What remains is your result - that is, highest power of 2 that divides the number.

Programmatically, let x is your input number. Then your desired output will be: `x - (x ^ (x-1))`

Explanation:

`x ^ (x-1)` [meaning x XOR x-1] gets rid of the first 1 from LSB (least significant bit) side

`x - (x ^ (x-1))` gets rid of the remaining part, and retains only first 1 from LSB side.

Answer (score 0):

```
def solution_3(N):
  # Range of the power of 2 that devides integer N
  A = range(0, N)
  # The list to store the values of N modulo 2**k == 0
  list = []
  # For loop to find all the values of k for which N % 2**k == 0
  for k in A:
    if N % 2**k == 0:
      # Append the value of k into the list
      list.append(k)
  return max(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple and easy solution which returned 100% in Codility

```
# you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
# print("this is a debug message")

def solution(N):
    # Implement your solution here
    highest = 0
    for i in range(0,N):
        output = pow(2,i)
        if (N%output==0):
            highest=i
        if output*2>N:
            break
    return(highest)
```